# Whitelist Travis CI to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, travis-ci

I'm having trouble working out how exactly I can whitelist my TravisCI runner for testing a python adaptor talking to a Google Cloud SQL service. The Cloud SQL will only accept connections from IPs that have been whitelisted ahead of time, though I'm not sure how reserve one from Travis (if such a thing is even possible). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the IP addresses of the Travis build machines [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ip-addresses/). If you add the IP addresses of the Travis infrastructure you use to your whitelisted IPs in Cloud SQL it should work. Keep in mind these IP addresses can change in the future though.